# How to setup Mosquitto MQTT Broker in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt

I have been trying to set up ChirpStack in a Kubernetes space, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, and I can't find any resources online that have been the solution.

```
**chirpstack-application-server-6d6f8d699c-nlrmx   1/1     Running            0          44s\
chirpstack-gateway-bridge-5454b7f9f-fm5wl          1/1     Running            0          73s\
chirpstack-mosquitto-646899d74d-d7bhl              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          85s\
chirpstack-network-server-66cdf9bdf7-rhzg5         1/1     Running            0          55s**
```

Above is every pod I have atm. App-server, net-server, gateway-bridge all spin up and run, however the Mosquitto broker moves to 'Complete' and goes right into the CrashLoopBackOff.

I have figured it might be something to do with a lack of config, so I've spent a few days putting together the mosquitto.conf file with "allow_anonymous true" hoping to get a connection from any of my ChirpStack components, but the logs just indicate an mqtt connection refused error.

**Output of kubectl logs chirpstack-application-server**

```
time="2020-12-10T15:01:41Z" level=error msg="integration/mqtt: connecting to broker error, will retry in 2s: Network Error : dial tcp 10.244.146.236:1883: i/o timeout"
```

Because no connection could be made, I assumed it was the opposite and I needed to add in the password_file and make allow_anonymous false. Below is my current config if anyone might have an idea what is wrong.

**configMap-1.yml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-password
  namespace: ****
  labels:
    app: chirpstack-mosquitto  
data:
  password_file.txt: |
    admin:admin
    user:user
    app-server:app-server
    net-server:net-server
    gateway-bridge:gateway-bridge
```

**configMap.yml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-config
  namespace: ****
  labels:
    app: chirpstack-mosquitto  
data:
  mosquitto.conf: |    
    persistence true
    persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
    # per_listener_settings false
    log_dest stdout
    # listener 1886
    listener 1883
    protocol mqtt
    # Defaults to false, unless there are no listeners defined in the configuration
    # file, in which case it is set to true, but connections are only allowed from
    # the local machine.
    allow_anonymous false
    password_file /.config/mosquitto/auth/password_file.txt
    #    cafile: /mosquitto/config/certs/ca.crt
    #    certfile: /mosquitto/config/certs/server.crt
    #    keyfile: /mosquitto/config/certs/server.key
    require_certificate false
    use_identity_as_username false
```

**deployment.yml**

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chirpstack-mosquitto
  namespace: ****  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chirpstack-mosquitto
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chirpstack-mosquitto
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: chirpstack-mosquitto
        image: ****/chirpstack/eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.12
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
        volumeMounts:
        - name: password-file
          mountPath: /.config/mosquitto/auth/password_file.txt
          subPath: password_file.txt
        - name: mosquitto-data
          mountPath: /mosquitto/data
        - name: mosquitto-log
          mountPath: /mosquitto/log
        - name: config-file
          mountPath: /.config/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
          subPath: mosquitto.conf         
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        fsGroup: 1
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
        supplementalGroups:
        - 1    
      volumes:
      - name: config-file
        configMap:
          name: mosquitto-config
      - name: password-file
        configMap:
          name: mosquitto-password        
      - name: mosquitto-data
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: mosquitto-log
        emptyDir: {}
```

**service.yml**

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chirpstack-mosquitto
  namespace: 186215-poc  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: mqtt 
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
      protocol: TCP  
  selector:
    app: chirpstack-mosquitto
```

Answer (score 5):

mosquitto/configmap.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-config
data:
  mosquitto.conf: |-
    # Ip/hostname to listen to.
    # If not given, will listen on all interfaces
    #bind_address

    # Port to use for the default listener.
    port 1883

    # Allow anonymous users to connect?
    # If not, the password file should be created
    allow_anonymous true

    # The password file.
    # Use the `mosquitto_passwd` utility.
    # If TLS is not compiled, plaintext "username:password" lines bay be used
    # password_file /mosquitto/config/passwd
```

mosquitto/deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mosquitto
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mosquitto
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mosquitto
        image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "50m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
        volumeMounts:
            - name: mosquitto-config
              mountPath: /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
              subPath: mosquitto.conf
      volumes:
        - name: mosquitto-config
          configMap:
            name: mosquitto-config
```

mosquitto/service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  selector:
    app: mosquitto
  ports:
  - port: 1883
    targetPort: 1883
```

now:

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f mosquitto/
$ kubectl get pods,deployments,services -o wide
$ kubectl logs -l app=gateway-bridge -f --all-containers
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/halkeye-helm-charts/mosquitto.git
2. Modify *values.yaml* file, adding *NodePort* or *LoadBalancer* and enabling the *storageClass*.

   ```
   service:
      type: NodePort

   persistence:
      storageClass: "oci-bv"
   ```
3. Deploy through *helm chart*: `helm install mosquitto --generate-name`
4. See the *mosquitto* pod logs: `kubectl logs pod/mosquitto-service-name`. E.g.:

   [image]
5. Test the service:

   Subscriber:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --name mqtt-subscriber efrecon/mqtt-client sub -h ip_address -p port -t "/#"
   ```

   Publisher:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --name mqtt-publisher efrecon/mqtt-client pub -h ip- address -m "SOOntestMessage" -p port -t "/test"
   ```
6. You should receive messages on the subscriber:

   [image]

Comment: Hi, I followed your description and got error 

`1672602620: mosquitto version 1.6.10 starting`
`1672602620: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.`
`1672602620: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.`
`1672602620: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.`
`1672602620: New connection from 10.244.0.1 on port 1883.`
`1672602620: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.`
`1672602628: New connection from 10.244.0.1 on port 1883.`
`1672602628: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.`